# run two commands in series jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run two commands in series and this is my CODE

**Edit** fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/MohamedAref/TLPPw/1/

**** HTML ****

```
            <div class="album large-11 medium-6 small-11 columns">
                <a class="album-link" href="gallery-window.html" onclick="" target="_blank">
                    <div class="clone_img"></div>
                    <div class="photos_cont">
                        <div class="photo"><img src="images/gal_1.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="photo"><img src="images/sticker_pic_1.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="photo"><img src="images/sticker_pic_2.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="photo"><img src="images/sticker_pic_3.jpg"/></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="album-title" href="">الجمال .. مسابقات و سلالات مختلفة</a>
            </div>
```

**** Jquery ****

```
$('.album').click(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    that.find('.photos_cont .photo').each(function(){
        // img_W.push($(this).find('img').naturalWidth);
        aimgcopy = $(this).find('img').clone();
        that.find('.clone_img').html('').append(aimgcopy);
        alert(that.find('.clone_img img').width());
    });
});
```

The problem is the alert command run during cloning operation so the alert() display '0' as an image width, So I want the clone operation complete before calculating image width.

How can I get this result ?

Comment: You should rather alert it on cloned image load.

Comment: How to do that **Milind** ?

Comment: have look at .load function https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: It works semi-successful as the alert display the width of the last image only !!!

Comment: can you share the fiddle.

Comment: this is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/MohamedAref/TLPPw/1/

Comment: see the answer below.

Comment: @Mohamed, reacting on image load in order to compute the width may not be the best approach here. Did you consider getting the width of the original image element instead? Since the new one is a clone, their widths should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('.album').click(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    that.find('.photos_cont .photo').each(function(){
    aimgcopy = $(this).find('img').clone();
    $('.clone_img img').load(function(){
        alert($(this)[0].height);
    });
    that.find('.clone_img').html('').append(aimgcopy);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Be careful: the `load` event might have already been triggered since you're registering your handler after appending the new image to the DOM. For once, setting the DOM0 `onload` property before appending may be the safest path.

Comment: if you test your answer you will see that the alert display the height of the last image only !!!

Comment: @Milind, maybe you misunderstood my comment. Your edit won't work because `$('.clone_img img')` won't match the new image before it's appended to the DOM. You could use event delegation, but alas it doesn't work properly with `load` events. I was referring to something like `aimgcopy[0].onload = function() { alert("..."); };`.

Comment: I don't understand you @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: would be great if you can help him out. i made all perm^n/comb^n but it didnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
$('.album').click(function(){
var that = $(this);
that.find('.photos_cont .photo').each(function(){
    aimgcopy = $(this).find('img').clone();
    that.find('.clone_img').html('').append(aimgcopy);
    aimgcopy[0].onload = function() { 
        alert($(this)[0].height);
    }
});
});
```

Thanks to `Milind Anantwar` and `Frédéric Hamidi`